# Filterin dataframe by another df

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, filter

Good day,

I got genomics data like this:

```
 chromosome start end 
 1          10000 10002
 1          10000 10005 
 1          10010 10012
 2          13123 13130
 2          13130 13135
```

I got target table like thus:

```
chrom location 
1     10002
2     13130
1     10004
```

I with to filter the genomics so that **chromosome** == **chrom** and **location** is between **Start** and **end**. Leading to data like thus:

```
 chromosome start end 
 1          10000 10002  
 1          10000 10005 
 2          13123 13130
 2          13130 13135
```

I tried to do this with joining and then filtering:

```
.join(target_table, [(target_table.chrom == F.col('chormosome')) ], 'inner'  )\
.filter((F.col('location') >= F.col('start') ) & (F.col('location') <= F.col('end')) & (F.col('chormosome') == F.col('chrom')  )   )
```

However, this seems to be quite slow and maybe silly. Is there more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you share the snippet of explain plan?

Comment: @Dipsy Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are asking for?

Comment: Just add `.explain(extended=True)` after your `filter` and share its output!

Comment: Also add your spark version please, and if possible: the size of the target table

Answer (score 1):

Use a broadcast join

```
new = df1.join(broadcast(df2),df1.chromosome == df2.chrom).filter(col('location').between(col('start'),col('end')))

new.show()
```

or you could try a SQL range join

```
df1.createTempView('table1')

df2.createTempView('table2')

#SELECT *
#FROM table2 JOIN table1 ON table2.location >= table1.start AND #table2.location < table1.end

 spark.sql("select * from table2, table1 WHERE table2.chrom = table1.chromosome AND table2.location >= table1.start AND table2.location < table1.end").show()
```